# Python3 / JS - How do I handle local file uploads with eel?

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, eel

I am currently working on a local Electron-like software with [Eel](https://pypi.org/project/Eel/).

This software is intended to be bundled as a standalone Windows application that needs to run on the user's local machine.

Within this software I want to be able to select and work on local files with at Python backend. To access the file, I use an HTML `<form>` with a `<input type='file' />`.

I'm wondering how I should handle the upload of local files within this framework as, unlike electron there is no `dialog.showOpenDialog()` function available in vanilla JavaScript.

The [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35654730/how-do-i-handle-local-file-uploads-in-electron) helps another user with Electron, but I'm searching for a workaround in vanilla ES6.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After fiddling around with JS and [HTML5 File API](https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-the-html5-file-api-to-work-with-files-locally-in-the-browser) (and failing very poorly to get the expected result), I remembered that I'm a Python guy.

The simplest solution to this problem that came to my mind is to let Python handle the File management. So instead of having an HTML `<input type='file'>`, I'm creating a button with an onclick JS function:

```html
<button type="button" onclick="getPathToFile()">Select File</button>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function getPathToFile() {
        eel.pythonFunction()(r => console.log(r));
    };
</script>
```

Meanwhile I let Python handle the file dialog on the backend:

```py
import wx
import eel

@eel.expose
def pythonFunction(wildcard="*"):
    app = wx.App(None)
    style = wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST
    dialog = wx.FileDialog(None, 'Open', wildcard=wildcard, style=style)
    if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        path = dialog.GetPath()
    else:
        path = None
    dialog.Destroy()
    return path
```

In JavaScript's console you then get `[1] path/to/selected/file`.

This method also allows you to execute actions on the file as if you were in Python (parse, save, modify, ...) and to display the information using HTML / CSS / JavaScript GUI.
Pretty neat.

Comment: Need another ')': (r => console.log(r)