# Python EEL + wxpython: open "parentless" file dialog in front of all other windows and programs

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython, filepicker, eel

I am developing an EEL project, and I needed to create a file dialog on the python side in order to preprocess data before sending it to javascript.

I tried to use tk.filedialog.askopenfilename, but that somehow froze the javascript event loop.

I found an answer on StackOverflow that used wxpython to create a non-blocking file picker. However, when I run the code below, **the file picker always starts minimized.**

However, once you use the file picker once, it works perfectly the second time.

Any help appreciated.

```
import base64
import json
from tkinter import Tk
Tk().withdraw()
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

import PIL.Image
import eel
import numpy as np
import wx

# Reusable wxpython App instance for the creation of non-blocking popup dialogs
app=wx.App(None)

eel.init("public")

def encode(bts):
    return base64.b64encode(bts)

def array_to_json(array):
    return json.dumps({
        "shape": list(array.shape),
        "dtype": str(array.dtype),
        "data":list(np.ravel(array).astype(float)) # not efficient but quite clean
    })



@eel.expose
def load_image(path):
    return array_to_json(np.asarray(PIL.Image.open(path)))

@eel.expose
def pick_image():
    # return askopenfilename()
    """ --- Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/59177064/5166365"""
    style = wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST | wx.STAY_ON_TOP | wx.DIALOG_NO_PARENT | wx.MAXIMIZE
    dialog = wx.FileDialog(None, "Open File", wildcard="*", style=style)
    dialog.Iconize(False)
    dialog.Maximize()
    dialog.Raise()
    path = ""
    if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        path = dialog.GetPath()
    else:
        path = ""
    return path
    """ --- """

eel.start("index.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working with the following code. I used a regular window instead of a wx.Dialog or similar class.

```
class FancyFilePickerApplication:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = wx.App()
        self.frame = wx.Frame(None,title="Fancy File Picker")
        self.build_ui()
    #@private
    def build_ui(self):

        self.vertical_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.control_panel = wx.Panel(self.frame,wx.ID_ANY)
        self.horizontal_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.control_panel.SetSizer(self.horizontal_sizer)
        self.frame.SetSizer(self.vertical_sizer) 
        self.dir_ctrl = wx.GenericDirCtrl(self.frame,wx.ID_ANY,wx.EmptyString,wx.DefaultPosition,wx.Size(400,300))
        self.vertical_sizer.Add(self.dir_ctrl,wx.SizerFlags().Expand())
        self.vertical_sizer.Add(self.control_panel,wx.SizerFlags().Expand())
        self.scale_factor_label = wx.StaticText(self.control_panel,wx.ID_ANY,"Scale Factor: ")
        self.scale_factor_textbox = wx.TextCtrl(self.control_panel,wx.ID_ANY)
        self.open_button = wx.Button(self.control_panel,wx.ID_ANY,"Open")
        self.horizontal_sizer.Add(self.scale_factor_label,wx.SizerFlags().Expand())
        self.horizontal_sizer.Add(self.scale_factor_textbox,wx.SizerFlags().Expand())
        self.horizontal_sizer.Add(self.open_button,wx.SizerFlags().Expand())
        self.open_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,lambda evt:self.submit())

        self.frame.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE,self.cancel)

    def open(self, file_picked_callback):
        self.file_picked_callback = file_picked_callback
        self.frame.Fit()
        self.frame.Center()
        self.frame.Show()
        self.frame.Raise()
        self.frame.ToggleWindowStyle(wx.STAY_ON_TOP)
        self.app.MainLoop()

    #@private
    def submit(self):
        filepath =self.dir_ctrl.GetFilePath()
        scale_factor_text = self.scale_factor_textbox.GetValue()
        scale_factor = 1.0 if not scale_factor_text.strip() else float(scale_factor_text)
        self.file_picked_callback(filepath,scale_factor)
        self.frame.Destroy()

    #@private
    def cancel(self,evt):
        self.file_picked_callback("",0)
        self.frame.Destroy()
```