# Store file in a local drive folder using electron or node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, file-upload, electron

I create one software in electron. I need to add image upload functionality into it. Uploaded images will store in a local drive(D:// Drive) folder and also on preview time I need to access the same folder so I have not idea it is possible in electron and if yes then how can I do this?

And for an extra thing in the backend, I use nodejs if you have an idea about that thing is possible using node js then also tell me so I can integrate with node js also. just I need to store that images to a particular folder which is in my local drive and I also access that image from my local drive for preview things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For selecting file to upload trigger event (ex. `upload-start`) through ipc from `render` process.
2. In `main` process in handler for this event use `dialog` module and `.showOpenDialog()` method which will return a path to the file.
3. Then in `main` process you can use `fs` module to work with file: read it, copy, move, rename and write.

And check [How do I handle local file uploads in electron?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35654730/how-do-i-handle-local-file-uploads-in-electron)